# Trouble with TableCellRenderer , trying to add a JLabel(image) in JTable Cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor

Here is my piece of code -

```
class ButtonCellRenderer extends AbstractCellEditor
    implements TableCellRenderer,TableCellEditor,MouseListener{

        JTable table;
        JLabel rendererLabel ;
        JButton editButton ;
         String text = "BAKRA";


        public ButtonCellRenderer(JTable table, int column) {
            this.table = table;
        rendererLabel = new JLabel("value.png");


            //rendererBut.setToolTipText("BUNTHAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
            rendererLabel .addMouseListener(this);


             TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
             columnModel.getColumn(column).setCellRenderer( this );
                columnModel.getColumn(column).setCellEditor( this );
        }

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row
                , int column) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            rendererLabel.setOpaque(true);

    if(isSelected)
    rendererLabel.setBackground( table.getSelectionBackground());
    else
    rendererLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);


            return rendererLabel ;
        }

        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
                JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
        {

            return rendererLabel ;
        }

        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return text;
        }

        public void mousePerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub




            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "UOBS BUTTON PRESSED",
                    "BUTTON PRESSED"
                    ,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }



    }
```

In this everything is working fine but -
Actually when the JTable window opens and if I click directly on the JLabel (image) based Column , then the image is gone for a while and the table returns the selected row as -1. 
One more point is that the Row selection as well restricted to the previous column.

> Precisely , If my Table has 4 column and Image(JLabel) is on the
>   column number 4th, then if I directly click on the image or column 4th
>   , then the row selection happens till the 3rd column and it returns
>   the row selection as -1.  But If I select any other column, the
>   everything is proper and works fine.

Comment: beware: that implementation of CellEditor is _invalid_ as it doesn't notify its listeners when it deems to be done with editing for internal reasons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to create a custom renderer to display an image. JTable already supports a default renderer for Icons. Just add an ImageIcon to the model. Then you need to override the `getColumnClass()` method to return Icon.class for that column and the proper renderer will be used.

If you are trying to create some kind of clickable button then you can use the [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) which also supports icons.

Comment: but how to avoid border and all as on using JLabel only the image is visible..and whats the actual flaw associated with my piece of code

Comment: I gave you working code. If you don't want a border then remove the border from the button. I don't know whats wrong with your code. since you didn't post a SSCCE. Creating a button editor is not simple. I spend a lot of time to come up with the solution I suggested.

Comment: Thanks Camickr .... i just provided button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
button.setContentAreaFilled(false); to make it my desirable.